# JavaFX TableView every row not a single object

Tags: javafx

I am coming from Swing where in a `JTable`, I can just set the column and the row to a value. In a JavaFX `TableView`, I have to make each row represent an object. I am trying to represent a schedule for a race track. I have round and race number, and then whoever is in each lane.

```
Round | Race | Lane 1 | Lane 2
  1      1      Bob      Joe
  1      2      Tom      Sam
  2      1      Sam      Joe
  2      2      Bob      Tom
```

Each object in a lane, (Bob, Tom, ...) is a `Car` object. It has various fields but what is being represented in the table should be whatever `toString()` returns, in this case, the driver's name. I have an array of `Round` object and each `Round` has an array of `Race`s which has an array of `Car`s for lanes. I need a way to represent this data structure in a `TableView` as shown above. Note that the amount of lanes, races in a round and total rounds can be changed by the user at runtime.

Comment: IMO, you can use `MapValueFactory`, create a map on the fly and put it into table view, [Example 12-12](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CEGHGDFA)